# Turning numbers into one piece of string vector in R

Tags: r, regex, string, character

When I use `as.character(1:5)`, my **current output** is: `"1" "2" "3" "4" "5"`. Is it possible to instead get the following desired output when we input any numeric vector such as `1:5`?

**Desired output:**

`"1 2 3 4 5"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `paste` with `collapse` argument.  It will coerce `numeric` to `character` and gives a single string as output

```
paste(1:5, collapse=' ')
#[1] "1 2 3 4 5"
```